# Pytorch: looking for a function that let me to manually set learning rates for specific epochs intervals

Tags: pytorch, learning-rate

For example, set lr = 0.01 for the first 100 epochs, lr = 0.001 from epoch 101 to epoch 1000, lr = 0.0005 for epoch 1001-4000. Basically my learning rate plan is not letting it decay exponentially with a fixed number of steps. I know it can be achieved by self-defined functions, just curious if there are already developed functions to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR) is what you are looking for. It returns `multiplier` of initial learning rate so you can specify any value for any given epoch. For your example it would be:

```
def lr_lambda(epoch: int):
    if 100 < epoch < 1000:
        return 0.1
    if 1000 < epoch 4000:
        return 0.05

# Optimizer has lr set to 0.01
scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=[lambda1, lambda2])
for epoch in range(100):
    train(...)
    validate(...)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
```

In PyTorch there are common functions (like `MultiStepLR` or `ExponentialLR`) but for custom use case (as is yours), `LambdaLR` is the easiest.